# Add 500 new objects to array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

It it possible to add 500 objects by for loop into an array using C#?

```
    public class DataBase
    {
        public Items[] GetItems()
        {
            return new Items[] {
                new Items (1, "item1" ),
                new Items (2, "item2"),
                new Items (3, "item3")};

                // for here?
        }

    }
```

The items should be unique :)
also first value in Items object is uint, so it should be converted somehow?

Comment: are u using a model for adding? or u just simple want to add using pattern above?

Comment: You can give this a try `return Enumerable.Range(1, 500).Select(x => new Items (x, "item" + x )).ToArray();`

Comment: @Satpal .ToArray(); at end of it  :P

Comment: @Satpal should it be .ToArray after => new Items (...) ?
1 more thing! "x" or first value in Items object is uint, how can I convert it to uint dynamically ?

Comment: @bodley, `new Items(((uint)x), "item" + x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class DataBase
{
    public Items[] GetItems()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1,500).Select(o => new Items ((uint)o, "item" + o)).ToArray();     
    }
}
```

Reference:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

Comment: what with uint conversion?

Comment: @bodley just cast `(uint)o`

Comment: perfect, that is what I need! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) and type case `x` to `unit`

```
return Enumerable.Range(1, 500).Select(x => new Items((uint)x, "item" + x)).ToArray();
```